# How to calculate an infinite sum using the Residue theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Please how can I calculate this infinite sum using the residue theorem

$$S=\frac{1}{B}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{w^n}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}$$

with $$ w = \frac{A}{B^2}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}\right)$$

and $A=\dfrac{k_1}{z}$, $B=1+\dfrac{k_2}{z}$, $(x,k_1,k_2)$ are reals and $z$ is a complex

According to a physical model, this sum has the general complex form

$$ S=f(A,B,x)+ \imath \,g(A,B,x)$$

Comment: A tip: you can simplify the form of the sum by combining all the exponential terms. That is, let $w = (A/B^2)(x^2-1)/x^2$. The sum is then $B^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty w^n/((2n+1)(2n+3))$

Comment: @eyeballfrog
 I'm one of them too

Comment: Why do you want to do it with the residue theorem? You could just do partial fractions and then sum the two resulting series by a suitable integration.

Comment: @joriki, according to a physical model, I think this sum has the general complex form
$S=f(A,B)+ \imath \,g(A,B)$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum_0%5Einfty+x%5En%2F%28%282n%2B1%29%282n%2B3%29%29

Comment: @Bob Dobbs thank you but I have already done it by mathematica, the problem is that it gives a purely real function and not a complex function of the form f(A,B)+ıg(A,B)
 and I'm looking for the complex form.

Comment: According to Mathematica $S $ is equal to a combination of functions $\tanh^{-1}(w)$ for $w<1$ but for $w>1 $ what does it give? I specify that $x>1$.

Comment: Yes, when $w$ is complex, the result of the sum will in general have both real and imaginary parts. One needs no underlying model to see this. You can split the result into real and imaginary parts eventually by writing the Mathematica result (in terms of $\tanh^{-1}$) using complex logarithms